# Does Objective-C changes overtime

Tags: ios, objective-c

Are there any changes in Objective-C syntax and version overtime like Python and PHP. Can I use Objective-C that was taught 3 years ago and use it today to make my app.

Comment: It's not the Objective-C part which changes fast. Cocoa touch, which you use to create iOS-App changes tremendously every year. If you start today I recommend an actual iOS7 book.

Comment: Actually, Objective-C *does* change quite rapidly.  The biggest change in the past few years has been ARC, but the way properties are handled is quite different, as are exceptions.  And there is the new `@` notation for collections.  And of course all the GUI stuff changes faster than one can keep track.  If what one was taught 3 years ago was the absolute latest (including ARC) then it's probably OK, with some time spent "coming up to speed", but if the info was at all "stale" you're in for a rough ride.

Comment: Apple updated Objective-C to 2.0 in 2006 which since then hasn't changed, one of the key updates have been to do with LLVM compiler and XCode IDE behavior such as they way you declare ivars etc. Take a look at the following wwdc 2013 videos for more infomation [link 1](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?id=400) and [link 2](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?id=402)

Comment: @ShamsAhmed The version number on Objective-C is meaningless;  since "2.0" was introduced, many additional changes-- some major (blocks)-- have been introduced without a version # change.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, it is always a balancing act. You can use all your previous knowledge, but you do not want to be stuck in the past, especially when there are advancements in the compiler every year. Things like ARC, removal of `@synthesize` for properties and the new literal syntax will improve your code greatly and save your time. I think before you start development, you watch the last three years' WWDC videos to see what's new in the language and compiler, and decide which you would like to learn. The changes are indeed rather minor in the grand scheme of things, so you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Since then the objective c does not have changes that makes impossible to you to do your app.

But since then the iOS version suffered major updates (like ARC, iOS 7, etc) so I recommend that you take that in attention before you start your new app.

Comment: iOS7 has nothing to do with Objective C syntax.

Comment: Same syntax. Just learn GDC, ARC and you ready to go. New APIs appearing in every new iOS version, but the language stays generally the same.

Comment: LeoNatan and Nathan are right, focus on GDC, ARC and see the WWDC videos and you are able to start.

If you will develop for iOS then, as @Nathan said, search all the new APIs that appears in those 3 years. It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Same syntax. Just learn GDC, ARC and you ready to go. New APIs appearing in every new iOS version, but the language stays generally the same